# Proving a limit using squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I would like to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n(e^{1/n}-1) = 1$ using squeeze theorem.

My attempt:

I used inequalities $(1 + 1/n)^n < e < (1 +1/n)^{n+1},$ to get$1< n(e^{1/n}-1)<n[(1 +1/n)^{(n+1)/n}-1].$

Now I'm having difficulty with the limit of the right side.  I tried using the Bernoulli inequality to get

$$(1+1/n)^{(n+1)/n} > 1 + (n+1)/n^2$$

This converges to $1$ but the inequality goes the wrong way.  I need an upper bound to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: using [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) for exponents $\le 1\,$: $$\left(1 +\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{n}} = \left(1 +\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 +\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \le \left(1 +\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3}$$

P.S. Without the squeeze theorem, you can let $f(x)=e^x$ and note that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x - 0} = f'(0) = 1$$

Comment: Thank you very much.  I should have seen that.  I would upvote but they say I don't have enough points since Im new

Comment: You were only a small step away. Glad it worked out.